# Inquiry for Ph.D admissions in European countries

Tags: phd

I want to pursue a Ph.D in Chemistry and the destinations of my choice are Germany, Switzerland, Netherlands and Sweden. Can anyone please tell me the scholarships and fellowships available to which an Indian student can apply in these countries? (I know of a DAAD fellowship for Germany)

I would also love to know if there is any centralized admission process to these countries (similar to US)? 
Thank you

Comment: The answers in the following thread should answer most of your questions: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24474/phd-in-europe-without-scholarship-from-non-european-homeland

Comment: There is no centralised admission in the US for PhDs.

Comment: @Greg: "Centralized" in the sense that you apply to departments rather than advertisements for individual PhD positions.

Answer (score 1):

PhD students in the Netherlands are usually employed by the university (these are AIO, or "assistent in opleiding", positions). As far as I know, anyone can apply for these jobs and it doesn't matter where you're from.

You apply directly to the faculty that is advertising the position, and after you are chosen for the position the university sponsors you through the visa process as a "[knowledge migrant](https://ind.nl/EN/individuals/residence-wizard/work/highly-skilled-migrant)".

Comment: There are also occasional grants offered by a body called NWO. The PhD grant is called Top talent, but it isn't always offered.